# Breeze Setting Multiple Foreign Keys On The Client-side

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, breeze, single-page-application

I have three breeze entities, my application is a long form that adds records to all three tables at once before going to the server for a save. Two of the tables Drivers & Vehicles have a relationship to AutoLead and need the AutoLeadId from the AutoLead table that is being entered all at once on the client side.

So I have a form, the user entered information into AutoLead, then adds records into the Drivers and Vehicles tables in one seamless form. How do I get the Id to assign to Drivers and Vehicles without first separating the saves out, and saving the AutoLead first, returning the new Id and then assigning it to Drivers and Vehicles before saving them again. I want to avoid multiple trips to the server just to generate the Id's for the navigation properties on Vehicles and Drivers.

From what i understood, breeze was supposed to be able to fixup these ID's using the temporary ID's from the client side it creates. But when i go to do a save it isnt changing these ID's. According to: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/navigation-properties

If i try to set the navigation property directly with objects, I get an undefined error for the navigation property (See code below). Using another approach, If I try to set the foreign key directly on their Id's I get a foreign key error from SQL because its trying to push -1 to the server (the temporary ID's). I know I must be doing something wrong. Here is some of my code:

**Create new client side entities:**

```
    // New entity creation functions
    var createAutoLead = function() {
        return manager.createEntity('AutoLead');
    };

    var createAutoLeadDriver = function () {
        return manager.createEntity('AutoLeadDriver');
    };

    var createAutoLeadVehicle = function () {
        return manager.createEntity('AutoLeadVehicle');
    };

    // Save Function Loop through all drivers and vehicles and set 
       their autoLeadId's before saving

    var saveAutoLead = function (newAutoLead, autoLeadDrivers, autoLeadVehicles) {

        // Loop through drivers and set the foreign keys
        for (var i = 0; i < autoLeadDrivers().length; i++) {
            autoLeadDrivers()[i].autoLead(newAutoLead);
        }

        // Loop through drivers and set the foreign keys
        for (var i2 = 0; i2 < autoLeadVehicles().length; i2++) {
            autoLeadVehicles()[i2].autoLead(newAutoLead);
        }

        manager.saveChanges()
            .then(saveSucceeded)
            .fail(saveFailed);

        function saveSucceeded() {
            return logger.log('Debug Message', 'Quote saved successfully', null, system.getModuleId(datacontext),
                    true, config.growlTypes.success);
        }

        return logger.log('Debug Message', 'Quote saved successfully', null, system.getModuleId(datacontext),true, config.growlTypes.success);
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad you figured it out.
I just wanted to point out that setting the FKs would have worked as well. 
In my testing using Northwind:

```
var em = newEm();

// acting as Vehicle
var ord = em.createEntity("Order");
ord.setProperty("orderDate", new Date());

// acting as Driver
var emp2 = em.createEntity("Employee");
emp2.setProperty("firstName", "Test fn2");
emp2.setProperty("lastName", "Test ln2");
emp2.setProperty("fullName", "foo2");

// acting as AutoLead
var emp1 = em.createEntity("Employee");
emp1.setProperty("firstName", "Test fn1");
emp1.setProperty("lastName", "Test ln1");
emp1.setProperty("fullName", "foo1");
```

I can associate emp1 to ord and emp2 as follows:

```
ord.employeeID(emp1.employeeID());
emp2.reportsToEmployeeID(emp1.employeeID());
```

or

```
ord.employee(emp1);
emp2.manager(emp1);
```

and in both cases the FKs will be resolved/updated after the save. That being said, I still recommend that you set the navigation property directly instead of dealing with FKs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sometimes I get confused when adding in the function () to the end of the variable is necessary to the object. For example, in my loop above for some reason on one of the loops I had to call autoLeadDrivers()[i]().autoLead(newAutoLead()); and on the other autoLeadVehicles()[i].autoLead(newAutoLead()); one without the () the other with, or it would error out, even though they are both observables.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out. For anyone having this issue, you must set the navigation property directly, don't set the foreign keys themselves. The fix was to push the navigation property as a function, so below is the fixed up code. Beacuse the breeze entity was wrapped in an observable I had to add it as a function with () at the end.

```
   // Save auto lead
    var saveAutoLead = function (newAutoLead, autoLeadDrivers, autoLeadVehicles, newAutoLeadDriver, newAutoLeadVehicle) {

        // Detach orphan entities
        manager.detachEntity(newAutoLeadDriver());
        manager.detachEntity(newAutoLeadVehicle());

        // Loop through drivers and set the foreign keys
        for (var i = 0; i < autoLeadDrivers().length; i++) {
            autoLeadDrivers()[i]().autoLead(newAutoLead());
        }

        // Loop through drivers and set the foreign keys
        for (var i = 0; i < autoLeadVehicles().length; i++) {
            autoLeadVehicles()[i].autoLead(newAutoLead());
        }

        manager.saveChanges()
            .then(saveSucceeded)
            .fail(saveFailed);

        function saveSucceeded() {
            return logger.log('Debug Message', 'Quote saved successfully', null, system.getModuleId(datacontext),
                    true, config.growlTypes.success);
        }

        return logger.log('Debug Message', 'Quote saved successfully', null, system.getModuleId(datacontext),true, config.growlTypes.success);
    };
```